# Numpy does treat float('nan') and float differently - convert to None

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a Numpy array form a normal array and convert `nan` values to `None` - but the success depends on weather the first value is a "normal" float, or a `float('nan')`.

Here is my code, starting with the initial array:

```
print(a)
array('d', [3.2345, nan, 2.0, 3.2, 1.0, 3.0])
print(b)
array('d', [nan, nan, 2.0, 3.2, 1.0, 3.0])
```

Now I would like to swap all `nan` values to Python `None` via a vectorized function:

```
def convert(x):
    if x != x:
        return None
    else:
        return x

convert_vec = numpy.vectorize(convert)
```

Simple, but leads to two different results:

```
numpy.asarray(convert_vec(a))

array([[ 3.2345,  2.    ,  1.    ], [    nan,  3.2   ,  3.    ]])

numpy.asarray(convert_vec(b))
array([[None, 2.0, 1.0], [None, 3.2, 3.0]], dtype=object)
```

Why is this? Yes, I can see a small difference - the second one has `object` as `dtype`. But using `numpy.asarray(convert_vec(a), dtype=object)` fixed it - both have `object` as `dtype` - but it doesn't change the difference in results.

Comment: Are those `array.array` arrays? Those are completely different from NumPy arrays. You should be using NumPy arrays. Also, the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) for `numpy.vectorize` says why you're seeing the difference in dtypes here.

Comment: You're showing two identical calls (`numpy.asarray(convert_vec(a))`) with different results. Is that what you meant?

Comment: The second one probably was `numpy.asarray(convert_vec(b))`, though even with that the results don't exactly match the code.

Comment: @MarkDickinson @hpaulj My bad, fixed it - it's a `b` in the second call.

@user2357112 I can not change that the original arrays are `array.array`, that's why I want to convert them to NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.nan` is a float value, `None` is not numeric.

```
In [464]: np.array([1,2,np.nan,3])
Out[464]: array([  1.,   2.,  nan,   3.])

In [465]: np.array([1,2,None,3])
Out[465]: array([1, 2, None, 3], dtype=object)

In [466]: np.array([1,2,None,3],dtype=float)
Out[466]: array([  1.,   2.,  nan,   3.])
```

If you try to create an array that contains `None`, the result will be a `dtype=object` array.  If you insist on a `float` dtype, the `None` will be converted to `nan`.

In the `vectorize` case, if you don't  specify the return dtype, it deduces it from the first element.

Your examples are a bit confusing (you need to edit them), but I think that

```
convert(np.nan) => None
convert(123) => 123
```

so

```
convert_vec([123,nan,...]) => [123, nan, ...],dtype=float
convert_vec([nan,123,...]) => [None, 123,...],dtype=object
```

- trying to convert `np.nan` to `None` is a bad idea, except maybe for display purposes.
- `vectorize` without explicit result dtype specification is a bad idea
- this probably isn't a good use of `vectorize`.

Here's an alternative way of converting the `nan` values:

```
In [467]: a=np.array([1,2,np.nan,34,np.nan],float)    
In [468]: a
Out[468]: array([  1.,   2.,  nan,  34.,  nan])
In [471]: ind=a!=a   
In [472]: ind
Out[472]: array([False, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [473]: a[ind]=0   # not trying None
In [474]: a
Out[474]: array([  1.,   2.,   0.,  34.,   0.])
```

Or using masked arrays:

```
In [477]: am=np.ma.masked_invalid(a)

In [478]: am
Out[478]: 
masked_array(data = [1.0 2.0 -- 34.0 --],
             mask = [False False  True False  True],
       fill_value = 1e+20)

In [479]: am.filled(0)
Out[479]: array([  1.,   2.,   0.,  34.,   0.])
```

Comment: Oh my. I never came across the thought that my error could lie in `numpy.vectorize`. I feel bad, adding `otypes=[numpy.object]` did the trick.

But why is it not a good use of `vectorize`? I want to create a Numpy array and convert the values according to my needs, so I thought it's best to do it while creating the array? Since the other way would be to loop over every entry, but wouldn't that destroy all Numpy advantage?

Comment: `vectorize` doesn't make any claims about speed, though it is a bit faster than plain looping (as documented in earlier SO questions).  It's intended mainly as a way of handling broadcasting, so is most useful when dealing with 2 or more input arrays.

Answer (score 0):

hpaulj has explained well, here is an easy demonstration on how to do it:

```
a = [3.2345, numpy.nan, 2.0, 3.2, 1.0, 3.0]
print [i if i is not numpy.nan else None for i in a]
```

Comment: Don't us `is` to compare numeric values. While this is fine here, there's no guarantee that `0/0 is numpy.nan`

Comment: List comprehensions where my first approach - and then I wanted to do it in Numpy for performance reasons - I might be wrong, but I thought using `vectorize` methods would be way faster for array operation on every element. Plus, converting `nan` is only half of it, I also want to round and handle `inf` as well. Not sure if my approach is  reasonable though.

Comment: like i said hpaulj has explained everything to do with using vectorize. my solution does work without using numpy arrays. you can make the decision yourself. my solution can also handle inf or round numbers too. as you can see numpy.nan is a float just so it can be viewed in numpy arrays, but it shouldn't be...